# Android -> How do i find error using eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, error-handling

I Am writing one app. I am testing on my phone using eclipse. Sudenly my app started crashing but i don't have any errors in eclipse. I wonder how can i see, where is the problem, and what is happening ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see the log (and stack trace if your app crashes) in LogCat.

- In Eclipse, Goto Window-> Show View -> Other -> Android-> Logcat.
- On your device you can download [aLogCat](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jtb.alogcat&hl=en) and use it to view the log on your phone.

Comment: Do i have to set up something ?? Because it is empty all the time, nothing is showing ??

Comment: are you testing on an emulator or a device?  Go to your devices tab in eclipse and find your package under your device and double click it to make sure LogCat has the correct scope.  That may fix your problem

Comment: select the perspective DDMS , and in the Tab of devices, select your device and you will see the logs appears in the LogCat :)

Comment: I have som yellow error, it says : unable to open log device '/dev/log/main' ...... device is galaxy s I9000

Comment: is your device detected on the eclipse ide when you try to launch your app ? did you install the Samsung Kies ?

Comment: I found problem, in my kernel settings (semaphore for ICS) logger was disabled :)